# Cheerio not parsing through html a tags

Tags: node.js, api, express, web-scraping, cheerio

I followed a tutorial online to try my hand at building an API as a personal project. I'm new to this so I have no idea why the code in the tutorial works but mine doesn't even though I've only changed the website urls and the search keyword.

```
const PORT = 8000
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const app = express()



const newspapers = [
    {
        name: 'guardian',
        address: 'https://www.theguardian.com/international' 
    },
    {
        name: 'thetimes',
        address: 'https://www.thetimes.co.uk/russia-ukraine-war' 
    },
    {
        name: 'telegraph',
        address: 'https://www.telegraph.co.uk/russia-ukraine-war/' 
    },
    {
        name: 'cityam',
        address: 'https://www.cityam.com/?s=ukraine' 
    },
    {
        name: 'newyorktimes',
        address: 'https://www.nytimes.com/international/section/world/europe' 
    },
    {
        name: 'latimes',
        address: 'https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2022-02-22/full-coverage-russia-ukraine' 
    },
    {
        name: 'thesydneymorningherald',
        address: 'https://www.smh.com.au/world/europe' 
    },
    {
        name: 'un',
        address: 'https://news.un.org/en/focus/ukraine' 
    },
    {
        name: 'bbc',
        address: 'https://www.bbc.com/news/world-60525350' 
    },
    {
        name: 'es',
        address: 'https://www.standard.co.uk/topic/ukraine' 
    },
    {
        name: 'sun',
        address: 'https://www.thesun.co.uk/topic/ukraine-war/' 
    },
    {
        name: 'dailymail',
        address: 'https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/russia-ukraine-conflict/index.html' 
    },
    {
        name: 'nyp',
        address: 'https://nypost.com/search/ukraine/' 
    }
]

const articles = []

newspapers.forEach(newspaper => {
    axios.get(newspaper.address)
        .then(response => {
            const html = response.data
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)

            $('a:contains("ukraine")', html).each(function () {
                const title = $(this).text()
                const url = $(this).attr('href')

                articles.push({
                    title,
                    url,
                    source: newspaper.name
                })
            })

        })
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('Welcome to my API')
})

app.get('/news', (req, res) => {
    res.json(articles)
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on PORT ${PORT}`))
```

It sometimes returns a list if I only have the first 'The Guardian' url. Otherwise the articles list always returns empty. The tutorial code runs every time, so I don't think I'm being blocked from scrapping the websites.

The tutorial: https://youtu.be/GK4Pl-GmPHk

Comment: `:contains` is case-sensitive, so the problem is that there simply are no <a> links that contain lower-cased "ukraine". Use `$('a:contains("Ukraine")` instead. If you want to search for both, you would use `$('a:contains("Ukraine"), a:contains("ukraine")')`.

Comment: Ok yes this seems to work. Although I get different results every time I run the script. Is this because the list is growing over time as it parses through more results?